# navigation controller as root view controller only displaying black screen

Tags: swift, xcode

[image: This is what my storyboard looks like]

My root view controller is a navigation controller, which leads to all my other view controllers. However, when running, it just displays a black screen and I am unable to go further in the app to all the other view controllers. The only code I have to load it is in the AppDelegate.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UINavigationController?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code for loading the navigation controller if you have some.

Comment: All I have is the code from the AppDelegate. Edited post to include the code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have mistaken to declare 'var window: UIWindow?' in your AppDelegate class.

Comment: Yes I do have that line in my AppDelegate. Just tried changing it to 'var window: UINavigationController?' but nothing changed. Is there something I need to change that line to?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forget to check the box is initial view controller.
Go to the navigation storyBoard and try to check it.

Answer (score 0):

you did not have to change anything in Appdelegate.

just remove navigationController from storyboard and than select your firstViewController than do this from the option on top of the mac:=

1. Editor

   - Embed In

     - Navigation Controller